# What happens to unsecured debts which were secured in a Ch 13 bankruptcy when dropped?

Tags: texas, bankruptcy, court, debt

In some cases in a Chapter 13 bankruptcy, a secured debt can be partially converted to unsecured. For instance an automobile which was not purchased recently can be 'crammed down'

For instance a car which a debtor owes 20 thousand dollars but, at the time of filing only has a fair market value of 10 thousand dollars can have the bankruptcy judge declare that 10 thousand is part of the secured debt and the remaining 10 thousand is part of the unsecured debt.

Assume the debtor, through the course of the bankruptcy payments via the trustee, completes paying off all of the secured debts. The debtor then allows the bankruptcy to be dropped by not paying the trustee any more such that the court grants the termination of it.

I assume that the original creditor can then make the claim to the debtor that the remaining 10 thousand dollars is owed, plus back interest (possibly in an amount that exceeded the allowed interest in the bankruptcy) before allowing the owner to have a clear title? I would also assume that the note could be accelerated by the creditor such that all amounts are due and payable immediately and if not paid, would subject the debtor to having the auto repossessed?

Is that true, or does the ruling by the bankruptcy court that the automobile is only secured by a 10 thousand dollar interest still stand even though the bankruptcy is no longer in effect?

I realize that BK is filed in Federal bankruptcy court but does any Texas law apply or are there nuances applied differently by any federal bankruptcy court region?

Comment: The question would be governed entirely by federal law. There is a possibility that some subtle issues might be different between the 5th Circuit that includes Texas and some other judicial circuits, but it would not be a function of Texas law. Texas law governs exemptions from creditors but not most other aspects of bankruptcy law.